# How to add span tag in CakePHP HtmlHelper?

Tags: html, cakephp

I have a html tag -

```
   <li>
       <a class="" href="http://www.sitename.com/logout">
          <i class="icon-key"></i>
          <span>Logout</span>
       </a>
  </li>
```

I want write above html in CakePHP Html Format-

My Code-

```
<li>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link(
        $this->Html->tag('i', 'Logout', array('class' => 'icon-key')),
        '/logout',
        array('escape'=>false));
    ?>
</li>
```

My code is working fine but `span` tag not showing. How to add span tag in above html?

Thanks

ChatFun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this following code: Simply using two tags of cakephp with concatenating them using `.`

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
        $this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'icon-key')).$this->Html->tag('span', 'Logout'),
        '/logout',
        array('escape'=>false));
    ?>
```

Gives output:

```
<a href="/savaganza/logout">
  <i class="icon-key">
  </i>
  <span>Logout</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I need span outside of the `i` tag

Answer (score 0):

You can also do :

```
 <li>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link(
        $this->Html->tag('i', '<span>Logout</span>', array('class' => 'icon-key')),
        '/logout',
        array('escape'=>false));
    ?>
</li>
```